# MySQL query to count zero value using group by in the same table

Tags: mysql

Here's my "customers" table:

[image]

To get number of enquiries per for a particular month and year, I'm using following query:

```
SELECT YEAR(customer_date) AS Year, MONTH(customer_date) AS Month, COUNT(customer_id) AS Count FROM customers WHERE customer_product = 6 GROUP BY YEAR(customer_date), MONTH(customer_date)
```

I get following result:

[image]

You can see that as there is no enquery in the April month, so no row fetched for month number 4. But I want 0 value in Count column if there is no record found in that particular month and year.

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: You need to create a month table, then `LEFT JOIN` the month table to your query.

Comment: You have a`SELECT` that gets the months that DO have queries, and it would not be difficult to write a separate `SELECT` that finds months that not have any. I think a simple union of the two should do the trick.

Comment: @Eric you mean creating a calendar table using stored procedure?

Comment: @Jerry can you please show me an example

Comment: @user5307298 If you are going to use this query a lot, it's better to create a permanent calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a calendar table to represent all months and years, even those which do not appear in your data set:

```
SELECT
    t1.year,
    t2.month,
    COUNT(c.customer_id) AS Count
FROM
(
    SELECT 2017 AS year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2018
) t1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12
) t2
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON t1.year = YEAR(c.customer_date) AND
       t2.month = MONTH(c.customer_date)
WHERE
    c.customer_product = 6
GROUP BY
    t1.year,
    t2.month
ORDER BY
    t1.year,
    t2.month;
```

Note: The above query can probably be made faster by actually creating dedicated calendar tables in your MySQL schema.

The following index on the `customers` table might help:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON customers(customer_product, customer_id);
```

This might make the join between the calendar tables and `customers` faster, assuming that the `customer_product = 6` condition is restrictive.

Comment: Oh! so long query. Is there not any some simple option available?

Comment: You may try creating bona fide tables instead of inlining.  I only inlined for the purpose of illustrating the answer.  If your `customers` table be really large, then may not be much you can do to speed it up.

Comment: bona file tables. I really don't know about it. Anyway, I had used calendar table as stored procedure. I think there couldn't be any simple and easy solution to achieve my goal.